# Ошибка при запуске python django проекта

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Запускаю свой проект на django, но при команде `python project/manage.py runserver` выдаёт ошибку

Версия django - 2.1.1
Python - 3.7

### *код ошибки*

```
(myenv) MacBook-Air-Igor:drf-demo igorborzunov$ python project/manage.py runserver 
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x105f7b620> 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/Users/igorborzunov/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/Users/igorborzunov/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run autoreload.raise_last_exception() 
File "/Users/igorborzunov/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception raise _exception[1] 
File "/Users/igorborzunov/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)() 
File "/Users/igorborzunov/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/Users/igorborzunov/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS) 
File "/Users/igorborzunov/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate app_config.import_models() 
File "/Users/igorborzunov/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name) 
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed   
File "/Users/igorborzunov/Desktop/IU7/drf-demo/project/apps/core/models.py", line 13, in <module> class Student(models.Model): 
File "/Users/igorborzunov/Desktop/IU7/drf-demo/project/apps/core/models.py", line 16, in Student university = models.ForeignKey(University) 
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Comment: не очень понятно по ошибке. У тебя вылезает эта ошибка при создание проекта или после каких-то действий? Если после действий, то покажи код, что ты добавил, что последовало ошибке?

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с Django 2.0 все ForeignKey поля должны принимать в себя также значение 'on_delete', которое говорит как должно вести себя связанное поле при удалении родительского. Например *on_delete=models.CASCADE*

Подробнее: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/

Answer (score 0):

Измените данные в модели class Student таким образом, должно помочь:

```
student_university = models.ForeignKey(
        'University',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

или используйте:

```
student_university = models.ForeignKey(
            'University',
            on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        )
```