# Как связать две модели в Django?

Tags: python, django

Код:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.

class myblog(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "myblog"

    myblog_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    myblog_text = models.TextField()
    myblog_date = models.DateTimeField()
    myblog_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Comments(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'comment'

    comments_text = models.TextField()
    comments_myblog = models.ForeignKey(myblog)
```

Ошибка в консоли:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\DjangoProject\mysite\myblog\models.py", line 14, in <module>
    class Comments(models.Model):
  File "E:\DjangoProject\mysite\myblog\models.py", line 18, in Comments
    comments_myblog = models.ForeignKey(myblog)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Comment: добавьте `on_delete` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 благодарю

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/887102/322249 https://stackoverflow.com/a/44026807/10898133